# Eclipse Java EE New Maven Project: Could not resolve archetype

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jakarta-ee, proxy

I am using the latest **Eclipse Java EE** (Kepler) and trying to create a Maven project. When I attempt to do this, and finally click the Finish button, I get this error:

> Could not resolve archetype
>   org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:RELEASE from any of the configured repositories.

All I have done in terms of "set-up" is install Eclipse Java EE (I also installed the main eclipse standard 4.3 earlier). I am also on a work computer, and a proxy test I ran returned the result: **This request appears to have come via a proxy**.

This has driven me nearly insane, so any help would be great! Thanks!

Comment: Did you try checking the box next to `Create a simple project (skip archetype selection)`?

Comment: @TJamesBoone alright, selected that. But now I got an building workspace error: Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.5

Comment: I'm thinking you may need to install maven on your machine.  Is it Windows?  There is a good tutorial here:  http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-install-maven-in-windows/.  This may do the trick.

Comment: have you provided your proxy credentials in settings.xml and also is your maven pointing to correct settings.xml ?

Comment: does it work for you once you create project via command line? install maven first (as the one you used earilier might be bundled with eclipse) afterwards, try to create new project via command line (you can follow this one: http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/258-how-to-create-a-new-maven-project-from-the-command-line/) and let us know how far you came.

Comment: Alright, I cannot create a project via command line. Just typing in mvn -version gets me the error: mvn is not recognized.

I followed the instructions @TJamesBoone linked to in the comment above. My environment variable are set the same way the guy set his. I restarted my computer. Still mvn is not recognized... this is a killer!

Answer (score 6):

Please verify, in Eclipse, Windows > Preferences > Maven > User Settings, please check the User settings file (settings.xml) exists and the proxy setting inside that file is correctly pointed to your proxy server.

Comment: What it does not exist

Answer (score 5):

Adding the following inside "mirrors" section in the user setting.xml file.

```
<!-- mirrors so we can control the access of artifacts and avoid going to 
    the internet for artifact metadata -->
<mirrors>
    <mirror>
        <id>maven repo</id>
        <url>http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
        <mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>
    </mirror>
</mirrors>
```

The official Maven 2 repository is at http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 hosted in the US, or http://uk.maven.org/maven2 hosted in the UK.

Answer (score 4):

Remove C:\Users\ {your username}\ .m2\repository\org\apache\maven folder and try to create your maven project again.

Answer (score 2):

You can also add

```
<mirror>
  <id>ibiblio.org</id>
  <url>http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/maven2</url>
  <mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>
</mirror>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Best solution as below:**

1. Close Eclipse
2. Delete repository folder (you can find it in C:\Users{your user}.m2)
3. Open Eclipse again. It will install maven repository automatically

Answer (score 1):

1. Open Window > Preferences
2. Open Maven > Archetypes
3. Click 'Add Remote Catalog' and add the following:

   - Catalog File:http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2
   - Description: maven catalog

Answer (score 0):

Besides what have mentioned, it's required for me to modify proxy protocol from **https** to **http**.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem and struggled lot to fix it out. I tried many thing including all the above answer.

I solution worked for me is, I created the first Hello World project through command prompt (while creating first time it downloaded lot of things) and then I tried in eclipse. It worked for me !!!.

To create from Command Prompt, please follow the video from the below link.

https://javabrains.io/courses/buildsys_mavenintro/lessons/Introduction-and-Setting-up-Part-1

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes

Answer (score 0):

This exact same problem i came through but instead of quickstart, for me it was webapp.

What i did to resolve the issue was:

step 1) to simply go down to path C:\Users\$username$\.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\archetypes\maven-archetype-webapp and delete the folder named "maven-archetype-webapp" (for you it may be quickstart). Yes delete the whole folder.

step 2) give your system internet access

step 3) close eclipse and and restart it again

what it will do is download the repository again.

This solution worked for me.